# How to make html table that perfect even in a small page and width

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a page who have left and right side who is in all page.

Now I want to make a table in middlecontent but their is very few space I can't make it big.

When I created it it's work but most of part was hidden [go behind right panel].

How  can I make some style then they show all content in a width and height I have means nothing goes hidden. Everything need to show even I show information using many line for particular rows [td].

Any suggestion of how to do this?

Comment: Show us some CSS / HTML code of your current layout

Comment: Yeah agree with above, quite difficult to give a good answer without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I not sure I understand your question.

try use this :
<table style="width:100%">

if it doesn't help you, link to your page, or copy the code. so we can understand better the problem.

Comment: I think, the table is to large not to small. I think some parts of the webside are floating over the table.